# Flash player does not work with mediaelement.js and FLV file

Tags: flv, mediaelement.js, flvplayback, flvplayer

I have a great echosystem with .FLV files, and need to play it, but my player does not works.

```
<script src="mediaelement/build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaelement/build/mediaelementplayer.min.css" />

<video width="640" height="480" id="player2" poster="myposters/flv-video-poster.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none">

    <object width="640" height="480" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="mediaelement/build/flashmediaelement.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="mediaelement/build/flashmediaelement.swf" /> 
        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&poster=myposters/flv-video-poster.jpg&file=medias/my-video-flv.flv" />
        <!-- Image fall back for non-HTML5 browser with JavaScript turned off and no Flash player installed -->
        <img src="myposters/flv-video-poster.jpg" width="640" height="480" alt="Here we are" title="No video playback capabilities" />
    </object>

</video>
```

I'm tested it in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 10, 9 and does not works... on IE 7 and 8 it crashes... and browser is restarted...

Comment: Define "does not work"

Comment: Simply... nothing happens... no flash player is rendered.

Comment: F12 on chrome check the console for the actual errors plz. We are not fortune tellers.

Comment: No errors appears in  the console

Answer (score 0):

Now is working:

I've follow this thread and it's working now: [Mediaelement.js malfunction in IE, no flashback works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190831/mediaelement-js-malfunction-in-ie-no-flashback-works), except in IE8 (browser crashes).

In IE9 and IE10 - Works HTML5
In IE 7 - Works Fallback SWF
In IE 8 - Browser Crashes

For me is good because is an private app and will use only google chrome or safari. If any customer needs to use IE will be used 9 or later.

Thank you all