# what is mode:shim actually doing?

Tags: mediaelement.js

what does `mode:shim` do?

i searched this site for a method of forcing flash.  the code developer wrote this answer to a question from someone having the exact problem i am facing:

[MediaElement.js - force Chrome to use flash player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111222/mediaelement-js-force-chrome-to-use-flash-player)

my observation is that modern browsers load an html5 component, then switch to flash, but very confusing on its actual behavior.

Answer (score 9):

As you said, it will force the flash fallback. in case of modern browsers, the init of html5 video will be overruled by the flash fallback.

```
// allows testing on HTML5, flash, silverlight
// auto: attempts to detect what the browser can do
// auto_plugin: prefer plugins and then attempt native HTML5
// native: forces HTML5 playback
// shim: disallows HTML5, will attempt either Flash or Silverlight
// none: forces fallback view
```