# shoutcast stream not working using mediaelement js audio player on latest firefox 21

Tags: firefox, html5-audio, mediaelement.js, shoutcast

The shoutcast stream not working using mediaelement js audio  player on latest firefox 21. Its working on other browsers like Chrome and IE.

You check the link below. It was working earlier with older Firefox.

[Test link](http://www.iseetv.biz/media/view/21354)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be be only solved by flash fallback for Firefox browsers.
You can find following line in JS code

```
t.supportsMediaTag = (typeof v.canPlayType !== 'undefined' || t.isBustedAndroid ) ;
```

change to

```
t.supportsMediaTag = (typeof v.canPlayType !== 'undefined' || t.isBustedAndroid )&& ( !t.isFirefox) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if you find a solution to this issue. I'm encountering the exact same problem.

[edit] I found a solution. Add the parameter "mode: 'shim'" to where you setup your Mediaelement.js media player to force a fallback to flash/silverlight for the component.

For more detail, read the first comment here : [what is mode:shim actually doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084587/what-is-modeshim-actually-doing)

I'm working on a way to make it only do this for firefox, but forcing this fallback for all browsers won't break anything, so it's a good solution in the short term.

Comment: yes thats right  after initial debug i found, either i can turn flash always on or let script decide.

Comment: yes that's right after initial debug i found, either i can turn flash always on or let script decide. So i modified my code to fallback only in case of firefox. You get the JS from test link above. Its working now. I shall mark this question closed.